# Google Maps overlays from CSV

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps, csv

I have a CSV file with names and addresses. I need to plot markers on a Google Map using the data in the CSV file. I understand how to create markers by looping through an XML file, but not from a CSV. I also know that a CSV file can be converted to XML.

Manually converting the CSV to XML is not an option. I should be able to upload a new CSV file to my server, overwriting the old one. When the webpage is visited, it should (I guess) run a script that converts the CSV to XML, and then reads the data from the XML and plots that on a map.

Am I on the right track with this? Have I overcomplicated an otherwise simple problem? How should I go about solving it?

Comment: It's easier to extract data from a csv than it is from XML, so why do any conversion? fgetcsv() is your friend.

Comment: Hmm, I managed to print the contents of the CSV with PHP, but now I'm not sure how to take that data and feed it into the Google Maps API. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/08/10/google-maps.html?page=2

Comment: Rather than simply pointing to the tutorial you're using, why not show us the structure and a sample of the CSV file that you've got... that might make it easier for us to help.

Comment: You would just have to parse the csv file (use fgetcsv() as suggested) and use the data just as before. Also, I notice the tutorial uses the version 2 of the google maps api, which is deprecated. I suggest using the 3rd version ;)

Comment: Oh, and the addresses in the CSV aren't geocoded. I suppose I would need to somehow geocode the addresses before coordinates can be fed into gMaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried uploading your CSV to Fusion Tables? Fusion Tables will display your CSV data on a Google Map. To create a new Fusion Table:

1. Go to [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com).
2. Select Create > Tables.
3. Follow the steps to import the CSV.
4. When the data has been imported, select Visualize > Map, and you will see your data on a Google Map.
5. The map can be embedded, or you can use the [Fusion Tables Layer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#FusionTables) in the Maps API, to display your map on a website.

If the CSV is constantly changing, you can use the [Fusion Tables API](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/) to update the data in the table.